# ImageFilter.Blur() clips the edges off when applying the blur effect to a text field?

Tags: flutter

I want to offer the user an option to blur certain text fields containing sensitive information, just in case they want to share a screenshot of my app without showing that information to others.

In essence, I'm looking for an effect equivalent to this: https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/5596

(You can increase the blur in the above snippet to `10px` so you can see what I want)

To achieve this in Flutter, I'm nesting the `Text` widget inside an `ImageFiltered` widget, and conditionally applying an `ImageFilter.blur()` effect to it. So far so good.

However... the effect doesn't look completely right:

[image: clipped blur effect]

As you can see in the screenshot, the blur effect seems to get clipped at the edges, making it look ugly.

Things I've tried:

- Using all possible `TileMode` values in the `tileMode` parameter
- Adding (lots of) padding around it
- Putting it inside a large container
- Reducing the size of the text

But no matter what I do, if the `sigmaX` and `sigmaY` values of the blur effect are high enough (which I need to make sure you can't make out the numbers), then it seems the blur will "overflow" outside of the space that was "assigned" to the text widget... and Flutter will just clip it off.

Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone think of a workaround to make the blur effect look professional and not clipped around the edges?

Here's a minimal version of my code so you can give it a go:

```dart
return ImageFiltered(
  imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
    tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
    sigmaX: 10,
    sigmaY: 10),
  child: Text(
    "Sample Text",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

thus this helps?

If you only apply the image blur to the text, the blur effect will be limited to the text area. However, when using ClipRRect with clipping it with textfield as example,Though am using container as example to show, the blur effect tends to extend beyond the intended boundaries of the text.

But if you are using textfield better to separate the blur and textfield

```
 - ClipRRect
 - SizedBox - // height and width
 - Stack
   -[
     - textField
     - ImageBlur - // same width height from sizedbox and also 
//make ImageBlur to be wrap with Ignore Pointer to allow the 
//back of the image blur to be click and input text
    ] 



return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    child: Container(
      
      width: 200.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,  
        
      ),
      child:  ImageFiltered(
  imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
    tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
    sigmaX: 4,
    sigmaY: 4),
  child: Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
     vertical: 10,
      horizontal: 15
    ),
    child:  Text(
    "Sample Text",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)
  ),
  ),
)
    )
  );
```

[image]